# Conceptual Model to set of relations

Tags: database-design

I'm struggling on a past paper exam question and can't find anything in the lectures regarding this question.

- Student registers for one or more classes. The class can have 0 or more students. The date the student registers is recorded at the registration event. Create an ER conceptual diagram from the given information.

My solution:

[ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMsYo.png)

Here is the part i'm stuck with, then I have to turn the conceptual model into a set of relations. Would it be {(student, registration, class)} or is it looking for the step-by-step procedure of indentifying the entities, relationships, keys etc? Does it want me to turn it into a relational table with a parent and child?

I know I should ask the lecturer/course coordinator for clarification but at this present moment I am unable to.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Do you want to know how to build the relations in database or the theoretical aspects of the relations?

Comment: It's theory. It's worth 3 marks.

Comment: Also, do you think my ER diagram is correct?

Comment: Not exactly, to be accurate you need something like this https://lwoodyiii.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/asp-net-membership-er-diagram.jpg. But not sure your course teaches you like this way. But I think you need to at least mention the field names and mark the keys some how.

Comment: I should of mentioned it's in UML notation. We are being taught a weird way. It makes it difficult to find information relevant to what i'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, how your teacher expects. As I understand, we have a many to many relationship with class and student. To make that work we need to use a third table which can be called registration where we will build 2 one to many relationships :

1. Each student can have multiple registrations (one to many relationship between student and registration.)
2. Each class can have multiple registrations (one to many relationship between class and registration)

For simplicity you can think about the table fields like this :

- student -> studentID (PK), name
- class -> classID (PK), name
- registration -> studentID, classID, registrationDate (Here should be a unique constraint with both studentID and classID.)

Comment: Pls upvote / accept the answer if it solves your problem. Thanks.